# journalctl for PulseAudio shows md.rk: RTKit errors

Tags: debian, pipewire

On Debian Testing when I run `journalctl -u pipewire` I'm getting errors like this

```
mod.rt: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
mod.rt: could not set nice-level to -11: Permission denied
mod.rt: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
mod.rt: could not make thread 1137 realtime using RTKit: Permission denied
```

Are these reasons for concern? My sound is working, but my device mixer isn't. I can't change the sound source off of the onboard sound to a USB sound card?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your user is not allowed to assign tasks to real time scheduling mode.

The best option is for you to add a new file 95-pipewire.conf in /etc/security/limits.d/ with this content:

```
# Default limits for users of pipewire
@pipewire - rtprio 95
@pipewire - nice -19
```